# Should I close my issues on abandoned GitHub projects?

Tags: github

This is a question regarding project management and collaboration between developers.

GitHub is now old enough that it includes many abandoned projects. The majority of my https://github.com/issues page is now issues I have opened on projects that have not had commits in years.

I would like to clean up my issues page so I can quickly find the important ones. Is the correct way to do this to just close all issues on abandoned projects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, closing the issue is the only way to remove it from this view. Note, though, that you can sort by recent activity if you don't mind having many pages of ancient issues. :)